# Find if current time fall into any of the given ranges in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table that looks like this.

| id | open_hours | other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ["09:00-14:30", "19:00-21:30"] | jj |
| 2 | ["10:00-14:00"] | kk |
| 3 | ["01:00-04:00", "05:00-08:00", "10:00-15:00", "16:00-00:00"] | pp |

and I want to know if the at the moment(NOW()) the store is open, i.e. it falls in one of the range given for a particular day. How can I do that within an SQL query? I am trying to achieve it by something like

```
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE TIME(NOW) BETWEEN one of the ranges specified in open_hours;
```

Comment: save data in a normalized database and also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Is this table structure designed by you? Or, is the a task or a test given to you and you have no access to change the table structure etc. and only have access to run `SELECT` query?

Comment: @FanoFN This structure is designed by me.

Comment: So, I assume that in `| id=1 | "09:00-14:30"` , the first value(`09:00`) is "open time" and the second value(`14:30`) is "closing time" for that range, is it? What `"19:00-21:30"` represents then? Also are these `open_hours` by `id` values are fixed or are these values being stored in; for example like need to press a button on a time-record machine - that will execute a command to store the "pressed time" into the database? Also you mention _"for a particular day"_ but the table don't have a date record.

Comment: What is **precise** MySQL version? *I have a table that looks like this.* Provide it as CREATE TABLE +INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: Just because MySQL supports JSON does not mean you HAVE to use it. Normalize the data. Store ["01:00-04:00", "05:00-08:00", "10:00-15:00", "16:00-00:00"] as 4 rows, each having two columns with datatype = time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT test.id, 
       CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(jsontable.timerange, '-', 1) AS TIME) timestart, 
       CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(jsontable.timerange, '-', -1) AS TIME) timeend,
       test.other
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.open_hours,
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (timerange VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) jsontable
HAVING CURRENT_TIME BETWEEN timestart AND timeend;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30b7dfac8d89b774a7ddb29f890889d9

PS. I strongly advise you to follow the advice of [nbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5193536/nbk) and normalize the data.